# Pandas - populate list with dataframe values as strings

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am reading `csv` files from a folder and filtering tem into a `pandas` dataframe, like so:

```
results=[]
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join('/path/*.csv')):
  with open(filename) as p:
    df = pd.read_csv(p)

    filtered = df[(df['duration'] > low1) & (df['duration'] < high1)]

    artist = filtered['artist'].values
    print artist
    track = filtered['track'].values
    print track
```

where `low1 = 0`, `high_1 = 0.5`

`artist` and `track` print hundreds of filtered items as normal strings, but if I try to append them to `results` in the loop:

```
artist = filtered['artist'].values
track = filtered['track'].values
results.append([track,artist])
```

I see that I am appendding objects and types and `results` ends up populated with a fraction of the filtered items. I don't get what happens.

How do I populate `results` with all items as regular `strings`, in this fashion:

```
[['artist1', 'track1'], ['artist1', 'track2], ...]]
```

Comment: `artist = filtered['artist'].values.tolist()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create list of `DataFrame`s and then join them together by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html), last convert to nested lists:

```
results=[]
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join('/path/*.csv')):
    df = pd.read_csv(filename)
    #filter by conditions and also columns by names with .loc
    filtered = df.loc[(df['duration'] > low1) & (df['duration'] < high1), ['artist','track']]
    #alternative solution 
    filtered = df.loc[df['duration'].between(low1, high1,inclusive=False), ['artist','track']]
    results.append(filtered) 

out = pd.concat(results).values.tolist()
```

Another solution id append lists and last flattening them by list comprehension:

```
results=[]
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join('/path/*.csv')):
    df = pd.read_csv(filename)
    #filter by conditions and also columns by names with .loc
    mask = df['duration'].between(low1, high1,inclusive=False)
    filtered = df.loc[mask, ['artist','track']].values.tolist()
    results.append(filtered) 

out = [y for x in results for y in x]
```

Comment: `results = zip(filtered['artist'],filtered['track'])`